# error: conflicting types for ‘yylval’ extern YYSTYPE yylval

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I'm trying to run this:

stark.lex

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
#ifndef YYSTYPE
#define YYSTYPE char*
#endif
#define INTEGER 288
extern YYSTYPE yylval;
%}

%%
[0-9]+ yylval=strdup(yytext);return NUMBER;
    ...

(\)){1} yylval=strdup(yytext);return EBRACKET;
\n
[ \t]+ ;
%%
int yywrap()
{return 1;}
```

stark.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef YYSTYPE
#define YYSTYPE char*
#endif
#define INTEGER 288

extern YYSTYPE yylval;
extern FILE* yyin;

void yyerror (const char *str);
int yylex(void);
%}

%token NUMBER IDENTIFIER KEY_VAR OPERATION SEMICOLON COMMA SIGN MINUS OBRACKET EBRACKET BG ND PLUS
%left PLUS MINUS
%left OPERATION


   %left UNARY
    %%
 ...

    int main()
{yyin = fopen("prog.txt","r");
yyparse();
fclose(yyin);
return 0; }
```

with command:

yacc -d stark.y && lex stark.lex && gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c

But i'm getting this error:

```
stark.lex:15:16: error: conflicting types for ‘yylval’
 extern YYSTYPE yylval;
                ^~~~~~
In file included from stark.lex:5:0:
y.tab.h:88:16: note: previous declaration of ‘yylval’ was here
 extern YYSTYPE yylval;
```

It worked last winter and i can't undestand why it doesn't work now. I'm using lex and yacc on ubuntu.

Comment: Why do you have `#ifndef YYSTYPE` around the `#define` in the bison file? Either it isn't set and you want it set to `char *` or it is set, but it is set to something different and you want to override it...

Comment: @ChrisTurner, i just needed to set it to `char*`  for using this: `yylval=strdup(yytext);`

Comment: Just set it then & don't check if it's already set

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use `#define` to redefine `YYSTYPE`, then you need to do it *before* you `#include <y.tab.h>`. Otherwise, `y.tab.h` will make `YYSTYPE` a type alias (`typedef`) for `int`. Since both `y.tab.h` and `y.tab.c` also declare `yylval` (as `extern YYSTYPE`), there is actually no need for you to declare it anywhere, but you still need to put the `#define` before the `#include`.

If you use bison, there are much better (and more convenient) ways to declare of `YYSTYPE`. The best one is to put

```
%define api.value.type { char* }
```

into your `.y` file, for example just before the `%token` declaration. Then you can remove the `#define YYSTYPE` from both files, as well as the `extern YYSTYPE yylval;` declarations, since bison will put an appropriate `typedef` into the header file.

You really should compile your project with

```
gcc -Wall lex.yy.c y.tab.c
```

Then gcc will warn you about many mistakes. Both bison and flex will produce warning-free code, provided you put the following into your lex file:

```
%option noinput nounput
```

I usually recommend using `%option noyywrap` as well, since that will allow you to avoid having to write a dummy `yywrap` implementation.